# Trouble adding metadata to a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-spatial

I created a table in Oracle with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Roads ( 
 TYPE VARCHAR2(40), 
 ADMN_CLASS VARCHAR2(20), 
 TOLL_RD VARCHAR2(10), 
 RTE_NUM1 VARCHAR2(3), 
 RTE_NUM2 VARCHAR2(3), 
 ROUTE VARCHAR2(40), 
 LOCATION MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

Then I wanted to add metadata to the `LOCATION` column which will hold the geometry:

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA 
(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO, SRID) 
VALUES 
('ROADS', 'LOCATION', 
 MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY 
 ( MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, 0.5), 
 MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90, 0.5) 
 ), 
 8256 
);
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-13223: duplicate entry for ROADS.LOCATION in SDO_GEOM_METADATA
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1", line 48
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1'
13223. 00000 -  "duplicate entry for %s in SDO_GEOM_METADATA"
*Cause:    There are duplicate entries for the given table and column
           value pair in the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view.
*Action:   Check that the specified table and geometry column names
           are correct. There should be only one entry per table, geometry
           column pair in the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view.
```

I am not sure why it says there are duplicate values because I have not created this table before. It also tells me to make sure that table and column name is correct and they are.

Comment: So what does the trigger `MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not sure about the trigger. I haven't purposely added any

Comment: You might want to try `SELECT * FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ROADS' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'LOCATION'` to see what's there. You might need to use an `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statement instead. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created your table and executed your insert statement OK.

Once executed again, I was able to reproduce your problem.

The error "SQL Error: ORA-13223: duplicate entry for ROADS.LOCATION in SDO_GEOM_METADATA" definitely points to duplicate data.

This trigger MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1 just performs a count(*) validation on the following MDSYS table and raise the -13223 exception when rowcount is != 0 .

```
SQL> desc mdsys.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SDO_OWNER                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 SDO_TABLE_NAME                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 SDO_COLUMN_NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1024)
 SDO_DIMINFO                                        MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY
 SDO_SRID                                           NUMBER
```

Query mdsys.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE in order to validate its contents. You should find the duplicate record:

SQL> select * from mdsys.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE ;

```
USER1                            
ROADS
LOCATION
SDO_DIM_ARRAY(SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, .5), SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90,
 .5))
8256
```

To workaround this issue just delete that record from mdsys.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE.

Comment: thanks! I deleted the record and ran the code again and no errors

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because some space characters on the column_name.

```
COR_NB_SC_LON,COR_CD_EW_    LON
```

I have fixed it and it works.

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
values (
  'COORD_REF', 
      'myuser.CONVERT_DMS_TO_GEOM(COR_NB_DG_LON,COR_NB_MN_LON,COR_NB_SC_LON,COR_    CD_EW_LON,COR_NB_DG_LAT,COR_NB_MN_LAT,COR_NB_SC_LAT,COR_CD_NS_LAT)',
  sdo_dim_array (
    sdo_dim_element('long', -180.0, 180.0, 0.5),
    sdo_dim_element('lat', -90.0, 90.0, 0.5)
  ),
 4326
);
commit;
```